# Inject null to autowired @Resource member in spring unit test

Tags: java, spring

I have implemented some unit tests which use the [Spring Test Framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html). The tests include members that get autowired by name, e.g.

```
@Resource
private FooBar myFooBar;
```

I configured my test to be able to run with different configurations like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593530/spring-unit-and-integration-tests/4593727#4593727).

Some configurations do not allow to run all tests (e.g. no database available). I want to skip the test in this case. My criteria to skip the test is `myFooBar == null`.

```
assumeTrue(myFooBar != null)
```

I am facing the problem how to inject `null` into this member. I tried

```
<bean id="myFooBar" class="FooBar">
  <null />
</bean>
```

But this does not work (*Invalid content was found starting with element 'null'...*)

If I do not configure the bean in my context.xml I get a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`.

Can't be that hard for Spring to just inject `null` to my member - but it's definitly hard for me :-)

I have to add that my `FooBar` class has no default constructor.

Do you have any idea of how to inject `null` or how to ignore missing bean definitions on autowired test class members?

Regards
  K. Claszen

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163182/intentionally-setting-a-spring-bean-to-null/2163329

Comment: @axtavt Thank's I didn't found that. +1 for you at the linked location.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If You would autowire by type using `@Autowired` instead of autowiring by name with `@Resource` then You could do:

```
@Autowired(required = false)
private FooBar myFooBar;
```

Setting `required = false` will make Spring ignore this dependency if it cannot be resolved, as the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation) states.

You can still use autowiring by name with `@Autowired` using the `@Qualifier` to provide the bean name:

```
@Autowired(required = false)
@Qualifier("myFooBar")
private FooBar myFooBar;
```

For more info on `@Qualifier` see this [reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) page.

Comment: That sounds really good. Will be back in office on Tuesday. Will give feedback as soon as possible.