# Spring and NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

Is there any way to inject "null" value on properties which references undefined beans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You give no details about how you are doing your injection but this article may be of help [Inject null to autowired @Resource member in spring unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5745682/569659). I would encourage you not to set beans to `null` unless it is in testing. You can always have two sets of beans: implementation and stubs where the stubs are not full implementations.