# Is there any way to run the junit / TestNG test cases in test environment?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, testng, spring-test

I am new to the spring framework. I have some experience in rails framework.

I am planing to create 3 environment ( test, dev, production )

I have created profiles in my **pom** file for each of this environment,

If i want to change the environment i have to manually change the active status as true / false.

Once i changed the environment, my entire app is running in that environment.

My question is,

**"Is there any way to run the *junit / TestNG* test cases in test environment without changing anything in pom file?"**

Thanks,

Jon

Answer (score 0):

If you use maven profiles you can trigger them in [several](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html#How_can_a_profile_be_triggered_How_does_this_vary_according_to_the_type_of_profile_being_used) ways. The easiest thing for you seems to explicitly specified the profile using the `-P` command line option.

```
mvn -P [test|dev|production]
```

Beside that, Spring 3.1 will introduce [XML Profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145306/junit4-spring-hibernate-test-contexts-setup/7145543#7145543) - this can be a good way how you can work with different environments. It should be [released](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145306/junit4-spring-hibernate-test-contexts-setup/7145543#7145543) this year - although they have already a delay in releasing the RC1. Nevertheless I would give the Milestone release a try (I already did).

(Parts of this answer comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145306/junit4-spring-hibernate-test-contexts-setup/7145543#7145543))

Comment: @Claszen, i haven't think about running the test in console. I am running the tests in eclipse only. Thanks for your suggession. But how we can achieve this in eclipse?

Comment: @Jon I am not sure if eclipse considers your pom.xml profile settings when running JUnit tests - but you can try open the eclipse project properties and select _Maven_ - If you are using m2e there is a "Active Maven Profiles" input box where you can set the profile. Maybe this also exists in the former m2eclipse plugin.